# Array variable with fp package: How to use \FPeval in array?

Tags: fp

I want use array along with `fp` package.

> \FPadd\xx{\somevalues(1)}{\somevalues(3)} works well
>
> \FPeval\xx{\somevalues(1)+\somevalues(1)} **NOT working**

**How to use \FPeval in array?**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{siunitx,amsmath}
%\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newarray}{m}
 {
  \seq_new:c { l_hafid_array_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _seq }
  \cs_new:Npn #1 (##1)
   {
    \seq_item:cn { l_hafid_array_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _seq } { ##1 }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\readarray}{mm}
 {
  \seq_set_split:cnn { l_hafid_array_#1_seq } { & } { #2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { c }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newarray\somevalues
\readarray{somevalues}{1&2&3.5&4&5}

\begin{align*}
v_1 &= \somevalues(1)\\
v_2 &= \somevalues(2)\\
v_3 &= \somevalues(3)\\
v_4 &= \somevalues(4)\\
v_5 &= \somevalues(5)
\end{align*}

First number = \somevalues(1)\\
Second number = \somevalues(2)

\FPadd\xx{\somevalues(1)}{\somevalues(2)}
\FPeval{\xx}{round(xx,4)}%
sum of first two numbers = \xx

\FPeval\xx{\somevalues(1)+\somevalues(2)}
\FPeval{\xx}{round(xx,4)}%
sum of first two numbers = \xx


%
\newcount\count
\count=5
\FPset\ans{0}
\loop
%\somevalues(\count)\\
\FPadd\ans{\ans}{\somevalues(\count)}
%\FPeval\ans{\ans+\somevalues(\count)}
\advance \count by -1
\unless\ifnum \count<1
\repeat
%
\FPeval{\ans}{round(ans,4)}%
sum of all numbers = \ans

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you're using `expl3` anyway why don't use use `l3fp` instead of `fp`?

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik Not familiar with `expl3`. I copied `expl3` code, to define array.

Comment: The answer I posted deals only with making your syntax work as you'd expect. The array handling code could be changed to use `l3fp`'s tuples, which are a built-in way of handling arrays, so they have a good support in `l3fp`. You can take a look at the [LaTeX3's interfaces](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) to see what programming facilities it offers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code does not work because the way that the `fp` package parses its input. In TeX when you define a delimited macro the delimiter text must *always* be present, so `\somevalues` must always be followed by a `(`, then some text, then a closing `)`. When `fp` tries to parse your expression it separates the tokens and adds other tokens in between, then the error you get is:

```
! Use of \somevalues doesn't match its definition.
<argument> \somevalues  
                        \FP@gen@code {2}
```

because what follows `\somevalues` is `\FP@gen@code`, not a `(`.

Since you're using `expl3` anyway you can use its `l3fp` module, which offers an expandable FP engine. Being expandable means that you can do

```
The~value~of~$\pi^2$~is:~\fp_eval:n { pi^2 }
```

or even

```
\setlength{\textwidth}{\fp_eval:n{ 10*30 } pt}
```

Here I emulated `fp`'s macros `\FPadd`, `\FPset` and `\FPeval` using `l3fp` instead. Note that these emulated macros aren't expandable anymore.

Now you can do, for instance:

```
\FPset\ans{5}
\FPeval\ans{ans+10}
ans is: \ans % prints 15
```

Every macro, say, `\ans`, used as the first argument to `\FP<something>` is defined with the result of the operation, plus a FP word called `ans` is defined and will contain that same value, so inside an expression you can use either `\ans` or `ans`.

CAUTION! This does not perform any verification whatsoever if the involved macros are already defined, so you can accidentally overwrite something important. `\FPeval\pi{6.283185}` might not be a good idea.

Here's the code (I only changed the definitions of the FP functions; your array handling and test code is the same):

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{siunitx,amsmath}
%\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newarray}{m}
 {
  \seq_new:c { l_hafid_array_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _seq }
  \cs_new:Npn #1 (##1)
   {
    \seq_item:cn { l_hafid_array_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _seq } { ##1 }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\readarray}{mm}
 {
  \seq_set_split:cnn { l_hafid_array_#1_seq } { & } { #2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { c }


% Stolen from l3fp:
\fp_new:N \l__sandu_temp_fp
\cs_set_protected:Npn \sandu_fp_name:nn #1 #2
  {
    \cs_undefine:c { c__sandu_#1_fp }
    \fp_const:cn { c__sandu_#1_fp } { #2 }
    \__sandu_define_fp_name:cn { c__sandu_#1_fp } { #1 }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sandu_define_fp_name:Nn #1 #2
  {
    \cs_set:cpn { __fp_parse_word_#2:N }
      { \exp_after:wN #1 \exp:w \exp_end_continue_f:w \__fp_parse_infix:NN }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__sandu_define_fp_name:Nn { c }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \sandu_fp_name:nn { f }


% Emulating fp.sty
\NewDocumentCommand \FPadd {m mm}
  {
    \tl_set:Nx #1 { \fp_eval:n { #2 + #3 } }
    \sandu_fp_name:fn { \cs_to_str:N #1 } { #1 }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \FPeval {m m}
  {
    \tl_set:Nx #1 { \fp_eval:n { #2 } }
    \sandu_fp_name:fn { \cs_to_str:N #1 } { #1 }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \FPset {m m}
  {
    \tl_set:Nx #1 { \fp_eval:n { #2 } }
    \sandu_fp_name:fn { \cs_to_str:N #1 } { #1 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newarray\somevalues
\readarray{somevalues}{1&2&3.5&4&5}

\begin{align*}
v_1 &= \somevalues(1)\\
v_2 &= \somevalues(2)\\
v_3 &= \somevalues(3)\\
v_4 &= \somevalues(4)\\
v_5 &= \somevalues(5)
\end{align*}

First number = \somevalues(1)\\
Second number = \somevalues(2)

\FPadd\xx{\somevalues(1)}{\somevalues(2)}
\FPeval{\xx}{round(xx,4)}%
sum of first two numbers = \xx

\FPeval\xx{\somevalues(1)+\somevalues(2)}
\FPeval{\xx}{round(xx,4)}%
sum of first two numbers = \xx


%
\newcount\counter
\counter=5
\FPset\ans{0}
\loop
%\somevalues(\counter)\\
\FPadd\ans{\ans}{\somevalues(\counter)}
%\FPeval\ans{\ans+\somevalues(\counter)}
\advance \counter by -1
\unless\ifnum \counter<1
\repeat
%
\FPeval{\ans}{round(ans,4)}%
sum of all numbers = \ans

\end{document}
```

which prints:

> [image]

---

P.S.: Don't do `\newcount\count` because you'll redefine the TeX primitive `\count`. Use another name.

Comment: The code does not work for `beamer` class

Comment: @sandu It's because you are doing `\newcount\count`. `\count` is the TeX primitive which allows you to access a counter register. Once you redefine it you're in trouble (it worked for `article` because it doesn't try to define any counter at `\end{document}`; `beamer` does and chaos ensues). Change the name to, say, `\counter`, and it will work :)

Answer (score 2):

***Don't use `\newcount`*** if you don't know about its quirks: for instance, it doesn't check whether the control sequence is already defined. If you want another spectacular wreckage, try `\newcount\box`.

You're mixing syntaxes. Something like

```
\newarray\somevalues
\setarray\somevalues{1&2&3}

\somevalues(1)
```

is in `arrayjobx` style and is not something I'd use, because it can confuse the parser for `\fpeval`. Better standard argument delimiters, that is, braces.

There is no need to use `fp` when you're already using `expl3`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse,xfp}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newarray}{m}
 {
  \seq_new:c { l_hafid_array_#1_seq }
  \cs_new:cpn { #1 } ##1
   {
    \seq_item:cn { l_hafid_array_#1_seq } { ##1 }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\readarray}{mm}
 {
  \seq_set_split:cnn { l_hafid_array_#1_seq } { & } { #2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { c }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\sumarray}{O{15}m}
 {
  \fp_eval:n { round( \seq_use:cn { l_hafid_array_#2_seq } { + }, #1 ) }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newarray{somevalues}
\readarray{somevalues}{1&2&3.5&4&5}

\begin{align*}
v_1 &= \somevalues{1}\\
v_2 &= \somevalues{2}\\
v_3 &= \somevalues{3}\\
v_4 &= \somevalues{4}\\
v_5 &= \somevalues{5}
\end{align*}

First number = \somevalues{1}

Second number = \somevalues{2}

sum of first two numbers = 
\fpeval{ round(\somevalues{1}+\somevalues{2},4) }

Sum of the array \sumarray[4]{somevalues}

Sum of the array \sumarray[0]{somevalues}

\end{document}
```

The optional argument to `\sumarray` is the number of digits for the rounding.

[image]